# Как скрыть вывод echo на главном экране?

Tags: php

Написал условие

```
if($lastGlavaAll == $glava) $hidNext = '.<style>.theme_dark_ .next_nav {visibility: hidden;}.next_nav {visibility: hidden;}.but_mob_glavs_m {visibility: hidden;}</style>.';  echo $hidNext;
```

Код работает, но при загрузке странице сразу показывается echo в виде точек, потом уже отображается контент. Подскажите как сохранить этот функционал, но чтоб echo не показывалось при загрузке страницы? Просто чтоб если условие выполняется, срабатывала эта переменная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно понял суть вопроса:
php:

```
if($lastGlavaAll == $glava) $hidNext = '<style>.theme_dark_ .next_nav {visibility: hidden;}.next_nav {visibility: hidden;}.but_mob_glavs_m {visibility: hidden;}</style>';
else $hidNext = '';
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
....
<?=hidNext;?>
...
</head>
```

вы можете выводить код `PHP` в `HTML` и `JS` при помощи конструкции `<?= ?>`
главное условие, чтобы расширения файла было `.php`

Comment: Исправил, но теперь почему то не работает.

Comment: @ZAKATTACK сейчас перепроверю

Comment: @ZAKATTACK попробуйте удалить точки в начале и в конце переменной, перепроверил на конструкции `$hidNext = <style>*{background:red;}</style>` - работает. проверьте правильность написания классов и стилей; обновите страницу при помощи клавиши `F5`; убедитесь, что ничто не переопределяет стили после; убедитесь, что переменна выводится между тегами `<head>` и `</head>` и после подключения `css` файла

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться. Может что-то с кодом напортачил.

Comment: Всё оказалось немного проще. Достаточно было убрать точки, как вы сказали, и теперь все работает должным образом.